# Camera issue with metaio AR+

Tags: android, camera, metaio

I'm just trying to figure out what could I understand from this log:

```
02-06 15:46:49.263: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.263: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.283: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.283: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.293: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.293: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.313: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.313: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.323: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.333: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.343: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.343: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.363: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.363: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.383: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.383: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.393: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream   0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.393: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.413: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.413: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.423: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.433: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.443: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.443: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.463: I/QCamera3HWI(188): int qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::translateMetadataToParameters(const camera_metadata_t*): flash mode after mapping 0
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): mce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): sce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera-sensor(250): module_sensor_event_control_set_parm:1084 CAM_INTF_PARM_LED_MODE 0 
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): stats_port_proc_downstream_set_parm AF ROI sent x: 0 ,y: 0 dx: 0 dy: 0, weight: 0 
02-06 15:46:49.463: E/mm-camera(250): isp_util_set_param_crop_region, No change in crop info, nothing to update
02-06 15:46:49.733: I/QCamera3HWI(188): int qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::translateMetadataToParameters(const camera_metadata_t*): flash mode after mapping 0
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): mce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): sce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera-sensor(250): module_sensor_event_control_set_parm:1084 CAM_INTF_PARM_LED_MODE 0 
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): stats_port_proc_downstream_set_parm AF ROI sent x: 0 ,y: 0 dx: 0 dy: 0, weight: 0 
02-06 15:46:49.733: E/mm-camera(250): isp_util_set_param_crop_region, No change in crop info, nothing to update
02-06 15:46:49.733: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream   0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.733: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:49.993: I/QCamera3HWI(188): int qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::translateMetadataToParameters(const camera_metadata_t*): flash mode after mapping 0
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): mce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): sce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera-sensor(250): module_sensor_event_control_set_parm:1084 CAM_INTF_PARM_LED_MODE 0 
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): stats_port_proc_downstream_set_parm AF ROI sent x: 0 ,y: 0 dx: 0 dy: 0, weight: 0 
02-06 15:46:49.993: E/mm-camera(250): isp_util_set_param_crop_region, No change in crop info, nothing to update
02-06 15:46:50.013: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:50.013: D/mm-camera-intf(188): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb8be8e04 type :5
02-06 15:46:50.264: I/QCamera3HWI(188): int qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::translateMetadataToParameters(const camera_metadata_t*): flash mode after mapping 0
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 6, is not   supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 6, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): mce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): sce_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): linearization_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): pca_rolloff_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): demosaic_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): demux_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): clf_set_params: param_id 8, is not supported in this module
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera-sensor(250): module_sensor_event_control_set_parm:1084 CAM_INTF_PARM_LED_MODE 0 
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): stats_port_proc_downstream_set_parm AF ROI sent x: 0 ,y: 0 dx: 0 dy: 0, weight: 0 
02-06 15:46:50.264: E/mm-camera(250): isp_util_set_param_crop_region, No change in crop info, nothing to update
```

It's something related to the device camera on a 4.4.2 kitkat device (Nexus 7).
I just can't figure out what is the specific problem.
Somebody has any advice please?

I ran the same app on other devices and never got any error like this.
Thanks for help and sorry for the big amount of code.